# sql that finds records within 3 days of a condition being met

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I am trying to find all records that exist within a date range prior to an event occurring. In my table below, I want to pull all records that are 3 days or less from when the switch field changes from 0 to 1, ordered by date, partitioned by product. My solution does not work, it includes the first record when it should skip as it's outside the 3 day window. I am scanning a table with millions of records, is there a way to reduce the complexity/cost while maintaining my desired results?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/eebe7

```
CREATE TABLE productlist
    ([product] varchar(13), [switch] int, [switchday] date)
;

INSERT INTO productlist
    ([product], [switch], [switchday])
VALUES
    ('a', 0, '2019-12-28'),
    ('a', 0, '2020-01-02'),
    ('a', 1, '2020-01-03'),
    ('a', 0, '2020-01-06'),
    ('a', 0, '2020-01-07'),
    ('a', 1, '2020-01-09'),
    ('a', 1, '2020-01-10'),
    ('a', 1, '2020-01-11'),
    ('b', 1, '2020-01-01'),
    ('b', 0, '2020-01-02'),
    ('b', 0, '2020-01-03'),
    ('b', 1, '2020-01-04')
;
```

my solution:

```
with switches as (
SELECT
  *,
  case when lead(switch) over (partition by product order by switchday)=1
    and switch=0 then 'first day switch'
    else null end as leadswitch
  from productlist
  ),
 switchdays as (
   select * from switches
   where leadswitch='first day switch'
   )
 select pl.*
 ,'lead'
 from productlist pl
 left join switchdays ss
 on pl.product=ss.product
 and pl.switchday = ss.switchday
 and datediff(day, pl.switchday, ss.switchday)<=3
 where pl.switch=0
```

desired output, capturing records that occur within 3 days of a switch going from 0 to 1, for each product, ordered by date:

```
product switch  switchday   
a   0   2020-01-02  lead
a   0   2020-01-06  lead
a   0   2020-01-07  lead
b   0   2020-01-02  lead
b   0   2020-01-03  lead
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can just use `lead()` twice:

```
select pl.*
from (select pl.*,
             lead(switch) over (partition by product order by switchday) as next_switch_1,
             lead(switch, 2) over (partition by product order by switchday) as next_switch_2
      from productlist pl
     ) pl
where switch = 0 and
      1 in (next_switch_1, next_switch_2);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=074e752ba5955877d0758059801ea384) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT (based on comment):

```
select pl.*
from (select pl.*,
             min(case when switch = 1 then switchdate end) over (partition by product order by switchdate desc) as next_switch_1_day
      from productlist pl
     ) pl
where switch = 0 and
      next_switch_one_day <= dateadd(day, 2, switchdate);
```

Comment: sorry for the ambiguity Gordon, my example misses an important edge case. I'm not simply looking for rows above with lead, I'm looking for dates within 3 days (important). So for example if you change the first date to 2019, it would be a year away, but still show in your results here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e7ceb9bb5ab34cc3fad94db304a6a8ad

Comment: @barker . . . I added an alternative version for that scenario.

Comment: hm, i switched up your solution (i think typos), but i believe its still missing some days, let me alter my question to include edge case. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c06dacf30215a56e6ee63a344eae975c